# como activar tecla Insert en VStudio

Tags: visual-studio

la pregunta es bastante concreta, no sé cómo activar el modo sobreescritura en el cursor en VSCode que normalmente se hace con la tecla Insert, el teclado anda bien ya me asegure de que Windows detecta la pulsación de Insert. Busque soluciones en internet y no me funciona ninguna, sin embargo en WordPad la uso sin problemas la detecta bien. Quizás algo relacionado con el setting.json? la verdad que estoy perdido.

Answer (score 0):

Era tan facil como añadir la extension Overtype a VSCode y listo, ya se puede entrar en modo sobreescritura.